# import C# form into c++

Tags: c#, c++, forms, import

Is there a way to import a C# windows form and user control into C++.NET? I'm using VS2008 and have VS2010 installed as well.

Comment: To clarify, I have designed the UI in C#. I would prefer not to redo my work in C++.NET.

Comment: Why would you want to so such a weird thing?

Comment: "import" means what? Being able to launch it I presume?

Comment: C++.NET doesn't exist.  It's either C++ or C++/CLI, which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a .NET assembly or control in an assembly it doesn't matter wheter you code and use it from managed C++, C# or VB.NET or any other .NET language, that's one of the reasons why .NET was invented: be language independent.

To use it: simply reference the .NET assembly in the new project.

Comment: Alright, did that. And I can run the form from my managed C++ main. The question is, would I be able to wire the form in such a way that the events the form generate go directly into my C++ instead of the C# code?

Comment: If these events are public just do it, it'll work, only the language differs, the underlying .NET generated assembly possesses all the mechanisms you are used to. See doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kz5cx8k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for reflector that will render the code as C++ (http://www.sandpapersoftware.com/Main/Reflector.html) - open your compiled-from-c# dll with that...

Answer (score 0):

Move your UserControl into a Class Library project and add this project as a reference.